Repulsive force within wave-function?
If due to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle a wave-function of a particle can never collapse to one singular point does this suggest some sort of Coulomb's Force like repulsive force that overtakes gravity at a small distance and keeps the probability spread out rather than collapsing to a point? I don't know how this would work since it is within probability and not physical matter, but does the charge or any other part of the particle repel itself from collapsing into an infinitesimal black hole or is there a different already known reason this effect happens?

There is no force. You simply cannot observe the position to infinite precision (as such a point would require), because of the HUP, which exists because the operators for momentum and position do not commute.

"I don't know how this would work since it is within probability..." Exactly: what does it mean for a force to act on a probability amplitude? Nothing! Be extremely careful when bringing classical intuition to bear on questions of quantum foundations.

This question probably originates from a widespread misunderstanding about Heisenberg's uncertainty relations (HUR, which are not principles but a theorem of non-relativistic quantum mechanics).
The physical content of the HUR is not that it is impossible to get a particle's position with arbitrary precision (after such a measurement, the collapsed wavefunction may be different from zero in an arbitrary small region). HUR say that if we perform such a precise position measurement, the resulting state will correspond to a huge spread of the possible momentum values.
After such a due clarification, the question could be recast as follows: does the spread of the momentum values originate from some kind of repulsion?
The answer is a clear no. Nothing in the QM formalism justifies such a point of view.

The wave function evolves according to a linear differential equation, the Schrodinger equation, whereas Newton's second law is a non-linear differential equation.  Newton's second law defines what a force is, so the concept of force doesn't directly apply to the evolution of the wave function.  However, if we were to try to reframe our view of the wave function as something that is subject to Newton's second law but with really complicated forces, then yes something similar to a repulsive force would be taking place to prevent the amplitudes from collapsing down to a single point.
